# What date / version is Chrome removing support for java applets?

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet

http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html

In September 2013, Google announced that their Chrome browser would no longer support the Netscape Plug-in API (NPAPI). This means that Chrome will block the installation of the Java plug-in used by our software through applet support, in legacy versions.

Google plans to gradually discontinue support for NPAPI during 2015:
•   In April, NPAPI support will be disabled by default, but Chrome will provide an override that can be applied by individual users (via chrome://flags) and enterprises (via Enterprise Policy).
•   In September, Chrome will remove the above override and NPAPI support will be permanently removed.

I have scoured around, attempting to find more specifics but without any information forth coming. Can anyone provide me with the date or projected release version in April 2015 when this feature will be disabled by default and similarly for the complete removal in September?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is on a roughly 6-week release cycle, so you can make educated guesses about which versions are going to be released in April and September. Specific dates are never available for future releases, so you're not going to be able to get a definitive answer for that part of your question.

Comment: I didn't realise Chrome was in 6 week cycles. I've looked at the release history and have confirmed that they usually work to 42 day sprints. As a result, we're going with the estimation of 15/4/2015 and 30/9/2015. Thanks for the info!