# Div tag over an applet

Tags: javascript, html, css, applet

I need to display contents of a div tag  over an applet.  Existing html page structure is somewhat like this:-

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<td>
<applet></applet>
</td>
<table>
<div>Overlap applet</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this?

No.  At least not in any way that will work reliably across browsers and versions of browsers.

By (browser maker) design, applets will either be entirely behind, or in front of, all other HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can overlap the applet by giving a z-index to both of them (the table and the div), with a higher value for the div.

Btw, the `<applet>` tag is not supported in HTML5.
You shoukd use `<embed>` or `<object>` instead.

Comment: *"Btw, the `<applet>` tag is not supported in HTML5."*  It was not an allowable element since HTML 4.01..  As an aside, it seems that Chrome is about to completely [drop support](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28716782/418556) for 'Java in the browser', making it moot.